# How to config a shared cache for multiple environments with C API?

Tags: berkeley-db

How to config a shared cache for multiple environments with C API?  Just like Java edition.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/GettingStartedGuide/env.html#multienvsharedcache

I want to open large number of databases, at least 100,000. But as the counts of databases opened increase, the db->open operation become very slow. It almost cost 2 hours to 100,000 databases.
So I try to distribute these databases to multiple environments ( for example, 5 envs ). And in order to improve the efficient of memory use, I want to share cache between envs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this with the C API.  However, consider some alternative solutions:

1. Use relatively small caches for each environment.  You need only have enough memory in each environment's cache to hold the working set of pages for a read.
2. Open all the databases in the same environment.  Though, if you need to recover each database independently, this isn't going to work.

It's likely that it's taking so long to open all those databases because your system is swapping.  But even a 1MB cache per environment is going to need 100GiB of RAM.  You may be able to get away with a 96KiB or smaller cache per environment, which is less than 10GiB.  Try 16KiB!

This won't wreck performance as it seems it might.  Your OS already does a pretty good job at caching data that's on disk.

If you can open all the databases in the same environment, that's even better.

Comment: I think you said the 16KiB means the database cache. I hava set the cache size to 5GiB in environment. It is an error to attempt to set a cache size in a database created within an environment, because databases opened within Berkeley DB environments use the cache specified to the environment.

Comment: Well, no... I mean a 16KiB cache in each environment, as it seemed like you were using one environment per database.  Clearly, with 100,000 environments, each one can't have a 5GiB cache!